# Yelp API call with python Requests

Tags: python, django

I've got a Django project with a class based view where my frontend makes a call to and sends through a user input. The View then collects that input and makes an API call and is expected to return a json object but I keep getting a 404.

I'm not exactly sure which part is broken as nothing gets returned.

Views.py

```
class YelpLocation(APIView):

  def get(self, request):
    API_KEY= '***'
    API_HOST = 'https://api.yelp.com/v3/businesses/search/'
    location = self.request.GET['location']
    headers = {
    'Authorization': 'Bearer %s' % API_KEY,
    }
    params = {
    'location' : location,
    'term' : 'coffee'
    }
    response = requests.get( API_HOST, headers=headers, params=params)
    return Response(response)
```

Comment: do you get 404 from `requests` or from `django`? you could use `print()` to see values in variables and which part of code works.

Comment: maybe in `Response(response)` you should rather use `response.text` or `response.content`, eventually `response.json()` if you want it as Python's list/dictionary.